# Can I autologin someone directly in app?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, authentication

So let's say I have 2 apps., basically  2 different targets , and I'm currently in the main one logged in , receiving a response from the server with a field that includes also the "user_id" . The question is if I can redirect the user to the other target ( open the other app if installed ) and forge a login based on the "user_id" which acctually is the user_id of that specific user for the second app.

I managed to open the other app, but could I force autologin the user and also open another VC and not the initial one.

Please ask me if you want more informations. Thanks

Comment: https://agostini.tech/2017/08/13/sharing-data-between-applications-and-extensions-using-app-groups/

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to go from `firstApp` to `secondApp`, you have to call `secondApp://` url to open the other app, now after the **//**, you can specify more information in **firstApp**, In your case , user_id:

```
secondApp://<Append your user_id here>
```

After this, you can handle this in your **secondApp** in AppDelegate like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleOpen url: URL) -> Bool {

    //Handle the url here
    //Extract the user_id from url

   return true
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I'll give it a try. Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: this appDelegate function is not getting called. It supposed to get called right after the secondApp is opened?

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel Edited the answer!

Comment: I've put some breakpoints but they're not triggered...maybe cause their designated for the 1'st app?

Comment: @FagadariuMarcel Yeah the URL delegate will be from **secondApp** as I've mentioned